# List files in Google Cloud Virtual Machines before SCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to download specific files from a google cloud virtual machine. The majority of directories that my google cloud command is searching in have just 1 file for that name. However, some directories have multiple files of similar name with different time stamps. Is there a command I can use to list the files within a google cloud directory so i can find the latest file name before using SCP?

I am currently using the following f string via os.system to download the files. However, this is not good enough for the case where multiple files are in the directory.

```
download_file = f"gcloud compute scp {project}:/nfs-client/example/documents/ID-{ID}/files/response* --zone=europe-west2-c ./temp-documents/ID-{ID}.xml"

os.system(download_file)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `gcloud compute ssh` command to get the latest file from a folder:

`gcloud compute ssh example-instance --zone=us-central1-a --command "ls -t /nfs-client/example/documents/ID-{ID}/files/response* | head -1"` or something like that

then substitute your scp command with the output from the above command to get the latest file.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want to do is download all the files in the directory. You can do this by passing scp the `--recurse` flag, like this:

```
command = f"gcloud compute scp --recurse {project}:/nfs-client/example/documents/ID-{ID}/files/ --zone=europe-west2-c ./temp-documents/ID-{ID}".format(project, ID)
os.system(command)
```

This will create a directory with the ID, and then put all the response files into that directory.

If, on the other hand, you'd really like to list the files, you could get a list by using gcloud compute ssh, and then fetching the output. You'll need to use something like `subprocess.Popen` instead of os.system, though:

```
import subprocess
command = f"gcloud compute ssh {project} -- ls /nfs-client/example/documents/ID-{ID}/files/ --zone=europe-west2-c".format(project, ID)
process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = process.communicate()
files = out[0].split()
```

A few things of note here: fetching a list of files via SSH like this is pretty hacky, and prone to potential breakage. Shelling out to gcloud to do this is pretty inelegant, and you're better off putting those files in something like Google Cloud Storage in order to easily access them from your local machine. The command needs to have your instance name (which you seem to be calling project), and your ID templated in -- I assume you're doing that, and just put in a placeholder. You also need to parse the output -- parsing with `str.split()` works okay, but could be error prone, particularly if there are spaces in the filenames. There are ways to handle this, but that's another rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
   gcloud compute scp instance-2:$(gcloud compute ssh instance-2 --zone=europe-west2-c --command "ls -t /nfs-client/example/documents/ID-{ID}/files/response* | head -1")  /temp-documents/ID-{ID}.xml --zone=europe-west2-c
```

Comment: This is good advice, but definitely bash and not the python OP asked for.